# Request Cookies in .net

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I need to read with **Request** the value of cookie in .net page.

This cookie is created with **Response** before with asp classic 3.

I tried  in asp classic 3:

```
<%
   Response.Write(Request.Cookies("PRBT"))
%>
```

and the cookie is valorized and output is correct.

But if i try in the .net page the cookie value in debug is null, why?

My code below.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
using System.Web;
HttpCookie PRBT;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            PRBT = Request.Cookies["PRBT"];

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["PRBT"] != null)
            {
                Response.Write("<p>" + PRBT.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 1**

```
using System.Web;
HttpCookie PRBT;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            PRBT = new HttpCookie("PRBT");
            PRBT = Request.Cookies["PRBT"];

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["PRBT"] != null)
            {
                Response.Write("<p>" + Server.UrlDecode(PRBT.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: when are you setting the cookie value?

Comment: I've edit my first post but the value of cookie is always null ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a cookies you should use

```
HttpCookie cookie=HttpCookie("MyCookie", "MyValue")
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

More detail about cookies

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/244904/Cookies-in-ASP-NET